# How to implement android TabLayout design support libarary with Swipe views

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablayout

I am going to use android TabLayout design support library but i don't know how to use swipe view.

**Here is my Code**

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java:

```
TabLayout tabLayout;

tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but to do that you have to use `ViewPager` class and use fragments for each view (under a tab). then attach `ViewPager` to your `TabLayout` instance and bingo! you have your swiping tabLayout.

Here is some working code of mine using two tabs:

**MyActivity.java:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
// Initializing tab and pager views
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_tab_layout);
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_view_pager);

// Making new tabs and adding to tabLayout
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("First Tab"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Second Tab"));

// Adding fragments to a list
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MyFirstTabFragment.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MySecondTabFragment.class.getName()));

// Attaching fragments into tabLayout with ViewPager
viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments));
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**SectionPagerAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;


public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "First Tab";
            case 1:
            default:
                return "Second Tab";
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFirstTabFragment.java:**

```
public class MyFirstTabFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Declare your first fragment here
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_first_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

**MySecondTabFragment.java:**

```
public class MySecondTabFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Declare your second fragment here
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_second_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Declare android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar or... here -->

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/my_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/my_tab_layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_first_fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Declare first tab layout here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_second_fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Declare second tab layout here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

**NOTE:** Here we use `ViewPager`, `Fragment`, `FragmentManager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` from support library v4.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. You have made the easiest tutorial about this on the whole internet. Again, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your java code :- `tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);`

Or alternatively you can specify this in your xml code :-
 `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

Comment: This will make tabs themselves scrollable NOT swiping views under tabs.

Comment: Thanks brother you solution helped me.

Comment: @Sourabh no worries mate.. :)