# How to create tabs inside Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-tabs

As shown in the picture

[image]

Is it possible to create Tabs inside `ActionBar`?

I have managed only to create `TabHost` but it goes under the `ActionBar` and not inside it (I think that is obvious that tabs are inside cause there is a perfect flow from `ActionBar` title to tabs).

Comment: share the code which u try

Comment: Those tabs in your picture are not in the `ActionBar`, they are **under** the `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 4):

As @Rami said:

> Those tabs in your picture are not in the ActionBar, **they are under
>   the ActionBar**

And you can use that with `TabLayout` (from support library) or the other libraries.which the `TabLayout`is the best option to use.

Here is a good tutorial: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

And check this link too: [How to implement android TabLayout design support libarary with Swipe views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313105/how-to-implement-android-tablayout-design-support-libarary-with-swipe-views)

**Example:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Take a look: [Tabs in TabLayout not filling up entire ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721498/tabs-in-tablayout-not-filling-up-entire-actionbar)

Answer (score 0):

According to Picture the Tab is not inside the action bar but the Tabs color and action bar color is same so that's why it look like